# [React][Mui] How to set anchor on Popover and pass it through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a TableCell Component that contains a Button and a Popover that opens with the Button.

```js
interface Props {
  productId: Uuid
  postId: string
}

const ApproveButtonCell = ({
  productId,
  postId,
}: Props) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null)
  const formOpen = Boolean(anchorEl)

  const handleOpen = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
  }

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null)
  }

  return (
    <BaseTableCell>
      <ApproveButton onClick={handleOpen} />
      <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
        <ApprovePopover
          productId={productId}
          postId={postId}
          open={formOpen}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          onClose={handleClose}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </BaseTableCell>
  )
}
```

To increase reusability, I want to change my component like this:

```js
interface Props {
  Button: ReactNode
  Popover: ReactNode
}

const PopoverButtonCell = ({ Button, Popover }: Props) => {
  return (
    <BaseTableCell>
      {Button}
      <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>{Popover}</ThemeProvider>
    </BaseTableCell>
  )
}

export default PopoverButtonCell
```

And I Use This Component like this:

```js
interface Props {
  productId: Uuid
  postId: string
}
const ProductTable = () => {
  const [approvPopoverAnchorEl, setApprovPopoverAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(
    null
  )
  const approvePopoverOpen = Boolean(approvPopoverAnchorEl)

  const handleApprovePopoverOpen = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setApprovPopoverAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
  }

  const handleApprovePopoverClose = () => {
    setApprovPopoverAnchorEl(null)
  }

  return(
  <Table>
    
    ...

        <PopoverButtonCell
          Button={<ApproveButton onClick={handleApprovePopoverOpen} />}
          Popover={
            <ApprovePopover
              productId={productId}
              postId={postId}
              open={approvePopoverOpen}
              anchorEl={approvPopoverAnchorEl}
              onClose={handleApprovePopoverClose}
            />
           }
         />
  </Table>
)
}
```

I thought it would work now, but I could see that the anchor wasn't working properly.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sNHh.jpg)

How do I make the Popover stick well to the Button?

Comment: Can you please create a codesandbox  replicating the issue?

Comment: @Akis
I solved this problem by creating a codesandbox.
I made a sandbox and it worked fine in it, so I compared it to my actual code.
I passed the key value to the TableRow by generating a random uuid, and this was the problem.

like this:
`<TableRow key={generateUuidv4()}></TableRow>`
`generateUuidv4()` generates a random uuidv4.

I don't know the exact reason why this is happening, but I fixed it as follows:
`<TableRow key={product.id)}></TableRow>`

Thank you

Comment: @Akis
Do you know why the problem occurs when the key is set to a random uuid?

Comment: for the popover to open relative to the button you need to specify the anchor and the anchored element in the right way. Can you please put the link for the codesandbox you created here to have a look?

Comment: @Akis [here codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sandboxtable-r2tcfl?file=/src/hooks/usePopover.js)

Comment: I have registered a new Question related to this code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73564214/how-to-create-a-reusable-component-for-large-number-of-buttons-that-open-a-form