# How to create a reusable component for large number of Buttons that open a Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

library used: `mui 5.4.1`

To create a `TableCell` containing an `IconButton` that opens a `Form`, the code is written as follows.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "001",
    name: "A",
    price: 2000
  },
  { id: "002", name: "B", price: 100 },

  ...

];

const SandboxTable = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table>
          
           ...

            {data.map((datum) => (
              <TableRow key={datum.id}>
                <TableCell>{datum.id}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{datum.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{datum.price}</TableCell>
                <ApproveFormButtonCell
                  toolTip={"approve"}
                  id = {datum.id}
                  IconComponent={<CheckCircleOutlineIcon color={"success"} />}
                />
                <RejectFormButtonCell
                  toolTip={"Reject"}
                  name = {datum.name}
                  IconComponent={<CancelOutlinedIcon color="error" />}
                />
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

```js
const ApproveFormButtonCell = ({ toolTip, IconComponent }) => {
  const usePopoverProps = usePopover();
  return (
    <TableCell>
      <IconButtonWithTooltip
        toolTip={toolTip}
        onClick={usePopoverProps.handleOpen}
        IconComponent={IconComponent}
      />
      <BasePopover usePopverProps={usePopoverProps}>
        <ApproveForm id={id} handleClose={usePopoverProps.handleClose} />
      </BasePopover>
    </TableCell>
  );
};
```

Then I have to create a `new ButtonCell component` every time a new button is added.

To avoid this, when ApproveForm is used in SandboxTable, handleClose could not be received.

```js
<ApproveFormButtonCell
  toolTip={"approve"}
  id = {datum.id}
  IconComponent={<CheckCircleOutlineIcon color={"success"} />}
/>
  <ApproveForm handleClose={??}/>
</ApproveFormButtonCell>
```

I need a lot of buttons open form.
Any good answers to solve this situation?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-framework-dcoslx?file=/src/component/SandboxTable.jsx)

Comment: The codesandbox doesn't run. There seems to be an issue with an imported component in the `SandboxTable` component. `ApproveFormButtonCell` also doesn't appear to take and render any `children` prop, so `ApproveForm` can't be rendered as a child component. The question is rather unclear.

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry, I forgot to saving after edit codesandbox.
Now the codesandbox will work.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, so the sandbox is running now, but what exactly is the issue? Based on what's rendering are you trying to add a button to either, or both, the approve and/or reject column cells?

Comment: @DrewReese
If you look at codesandbox, you can find `ApproveButtonCell` and `RejectButtonCell`.
In a real project, there will be many more kinds of buttons, and I don't want to create `a new ButtonCell component` each time. Instead, I want to create `a single reusable ButtonCell component` and reuse it. How can we achieve this?
Thank you for your attention to this matter

Comment: For example, I may need to add BuyButtonCell, SellButtonCell, etc., or keep adding another ButtonCell in a similar table. I think it's too inefficient to create a new component each time.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "create a new component each time". It's just a button right? A button has an `onClick` handler. Do you need more than one kind of button for this?

Comment: @DrewReese First of all, I'm a beginner, so I think my code might be smelly. In `ApproveButtonCell` I thought I should pass `usePopoverProps` to `Button`, `Popover`, and `ApproveForm` , so I create a new component file called `ApproveButtonCell`.
  This component is a TableCell containing `a button that opens a Popover` and `a Popover containing an ApproveForm`.
The biggest problem is that ApproveForm is included in this Component.
So, when I want to use another Form, I need to create a new `TableCell Component containing Buttons - like RejectButtonCell`.

Comment: In the current code, when there are many types of forms, create a new ButtonCell Component file for each form. But I don't want the number of files to get more and more. In a nutshell, I'm looking for a way to refactor this code into a more scalable and reusable.

Comment: I can't get the `ApproveFormButtonCell` component to render the icon button or the `ApproveForm` component in the popover. I have an idea for a refactor, but I need to get past what this component is supposed to open and render. Can you update the `ApproveFormButtonCell` so it renders alone how you like?

Comment: @DrewReese After logging out, I opened the codesandbox and saw that something was wrong. When logging in the Iconbutton renders fine, but for others it doesn't seem to. what's the matter....

Comment: @DrewReese how about this link? - https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-framework-dcoslx?file=/src/component/SandboxTable.jsx
Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep from making a one-off of every sort and type of form button cell component you can abstract the common behavior/UI, i.e. the `IconButtonWithTooltip` and `BasePopover` components, into a generic component and pass in as a prop the content that is different. In this case it seems the form component is what is different.

Create a general purpose component that utilizes the power of a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), i.e. a prop that is a function called during the render. This render prop will pass the close handler as an argument.

Example:

```
const FormButton = ({ toolTip, IconComponent, renderForm }) => {
  const popoverProps = usePopover();
  return (
    <>
      <IconButtonWithTooltip
        toolTip={toolTip}
        onClick={popoverProps.handleOpen}
        IconComponent={IconComponent}
      />
      <BasePopover usePopverProps={popoverProps}>
        {renderForm({ handleClose: popoverProps.handleClose })}
      </BasePopover>
    </>
  );
};
```

Example usage:

```
import CheckCircleOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CheckCircleOutline";
import CancelOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CancelOutlined";
import FormButton from "./FormButton";
import RejectForm from "./RejectForm";
import ApproveForm from "./ApproveForm";

...

<TableBody>
  {data.map((datum) => (
    <TableRow key={datum.id}>
      <TableCell>{datum.id}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{datum.name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{datum.price}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <FormButton
          toolTip={"approve"}
          IconComponent={<CheckCircleOutlineIcon color={"success"} />}
          renderForm={({ handleClose }) => (
            <ApproveForm id={datum.id} handleClose={handleClose} />
          )}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <FormButton
          toolTip={"Reject"}
          IconComponent={<CancelOutlinedIcon color="error" />}
          renderForm={({ handleClose }) => (
            <RejectForm handleClose={handleClose} name={datum.name} />
          )}
        />
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))}
</TableBody>
```

[image: Edit how-to-create-a-reusable-component-for-large-number-of-buttons-that-open-a-form]

Comment: Render prop! I've heard of it, but I don't know why or how to use it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @hyeogeon Yeah, render props, one of those semi-obscure, abstract React concepts that takes like 20+ readings of the docs and couple times implementing before it sinks in how trivial and easy it is to use and what use cases it solves for.